# How to import simple bit-src component into projects' /src folder?

Tags: bit-src

I'm trying bit-src (or should I call it bit.dev?) for the first time...

I have two files - a .ts with just 1 dependency and a .md with its docs - which I use in many projects, which I want to turn into a bit component.

So, I find these two files in the /src folder of one of my projects, add it as a component, tag it and then export it to my collection.  So far so good.

Then I go to another project that needs to share in the use of this component and I try to import it (if the files were already there I deleted them first)..

```
$ bit import <user>.<colx>/<component> --path src
```

I get an error message stating that the directory is not empty (which is true).

If I do install it into its own directory then it also creates a bunch of overhead I don't want, but I guess that's not the point - it should be in my /src folder along with other code, same as it was in the project I created it from.

Is there some way to do what I want?  Or should I be using a different tool entirely?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to change the default location of imported component, you can do it by edit the bit configuration in the `package.json`, from this:

```
"bit": {
    "env": {},
    "componentsDefaultDirectory": "components/{name}",
    "packageManager": "npm"
  }
```

to this:

```
"bit": {
    "env": {},
    "componentsDefaultDirectory": "src/{name}",
    "packageManager": "npm"
  }
```

If you want to use the `--path` flag, you need to specify the folder, like this:
`bit import <user>.<colx>/<component> --path src/<component>`

I hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  When I couldn't make this work and couldn't get an answer I gave up on bit-src, but when I get a chance I'll come back to it and give your solution a try.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using the `--path <foldPath>` flag places the component files directly at *foldPath*.
this would include the **/dist folder, node_modules, package.json**, etc.

So, it makes sense to do this in a new, empty folder.

maybe use import like this?
`bit import ... --path ./src/componentName`